# c# Direct X. . .

Tags: c#, directx

Hi i am new to directx c#. i have a problem in one project. i draw two cubes which is one after another (ie x and y same location z is different), but the problem is when i view the front cube it is transparent and back cube is visible through front cube, i checked the transparency, no transparent level has been set. cullmode=null,Can anyone suggest what was the problem in tat?

And I think that the pixel of back cube overlaps with the front cube , how to overcome this?

here the screen shots..

Front Facing: http://postimg.org/image/6irstpv75/

Top View:http://postimg.org/image/o7ktw54h3/

Comment: Screen Shots are: 

Front Facing: http://postimg.org/image/6irstpv75/
rear Facing :http://postimg.org/image/tyz5v3av3/
Side View:http://postimg.org/image/fmabaig8v/
Top View:http://postimg.org/image/o7ktw54h3/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :)

Please, consider adding **tags** to your post (programming language, "DirectX" etc) Without knowing which language you use (*edit: c#... you should write it in tags... Soo, which framework? SharpDX? SlimDX? :)*), i cannot be more specific.

Looks like you dont use [DepthBuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering): you draw your distant cube first and closer cube after it, so it override existing pixels on BackBuffer.

Comment: It can be more complex then just "enabling it" - for example, if you swap render targets, depth buffer can be nulled. (sorry, i accidentaly hit Enter :( So edit:) I can see on your FrontFacing screenshot, there is a line from grid which override your cubes too - i am sorry, but it really looks like you are drawing ordered wo z-buffer. Can you show some of your code, especially where you are enabling backbuffer?

Comment: This are the code i used....

presentparameter.swapeffects=swapeffect.discard
presentparameter.enableautodepthstencil=true
presentparameter.autodepthstencilformat=depthformat.16
presentparameter.presentflag=presentflag.discarddepthstencil

presentparameter.backbuffercount=1
presentparameter.backbufferheight=devicesize.height
presentparameter.backcufferwidth=devicesize.width
presentparameter.backbufferformat=adapterinfo.currentdisplaymode.form

Comment: Ah, so you are using XNA... Please add it in your tags ;) Chances are, you will lure somebody who understand XNA better then me :D Also, please edit your question with code you post here in comment.

Comment: (btw, just by quick peek in xna documentation: is `PresentFlag.DiscardDepthStencil` really what you want? Its hard to tell without context...)